# Getting NullReferenceException when using autocomplete to filter DataGridView

Tags: c#, sqlite, datagridview, datatable

I'm trying to make a TextBox that searchs all data on a DataGridView with autocomplete, and as the user types the DataGrid changes with the corresponding data.
The DataGridView also has a bindingsource from a table in a DataSet .xsd

**form load, putting the data in autocomplete collection**

```
        private void frmConMateriais_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var todos = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
            using (var conn = new SQLiteConnection(@"DataSource=" + Application.StartupPath + @"\teste.db"))
            {
                conn.Open();
                using (var cmd =
                    new SQLiteCommand(
                        "SELECT * FROM materiais",
                        conn))
                {
                    var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    if (dr.HasRows)
                    {
                        while (dr.Read())
                        {
                            todos.Add(dr["cod_material"].ToString());
                            todos.Add(dr["marca_material"].ToString());
                            todos.Add(dr["tipo_material"].ToString());
                            todos.Add(dr["quantidade_material"].ToString());
                            todos.Add(dr["metragem_material"].ToString());
                            todos.Add(dr["cor_material"].ToString());
                            todos.Add(dr["peso_material"].ToString());
                        } 
                       foreach (var tb in Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
                        {
                            tb.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
                            tb.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
                        }
                        txtPesquisar.AutoCompleteCustomSource = todos;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception erro)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Erro" + erro, "Erro", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            throw;
        }
    }
```

**textbox changed**

```
private void txtPesquisar_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var dv = string.Format("[{0}] like '%{1}%'", "Código", txtPesquisar.Text);
            dv += string.Format(" OR [{0}] like '%{1}%'", "Marca", txtPesquisar.Text);
            dv += string.Format(" OR [{0}] like '%{1}%'", "Tipo", txtPesquisar.Text);
            dv += string.Format(" OR convert([{0}], System.String) like '%{1}%'", "Quantidade", txtPesquisar.Text);
            dv += string.Format(" OR convert([{0}], System.String) like '%{1}%'", "Metragem", txtPesquisar.Text);
            dv += string.Format(" OR [{0}] like '%{1}%'", "Cor", txtPesquisar.Text);
            dv += string.Format(" OR convert([{0}], System.String) like'%{1}%'", "Peso", txtPesquisar.Text);

            //getting exception on this line
            (dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = dv;
        }
        catch (Exception erro)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Erro" + erro, "Erro", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you debugged it at all?  Are either `(dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable)` or `(dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView` actually null?  If not, what is the full `ToString()` output of the exception including the exception message, type, and inner exception?  Have you read [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4660142) and verified your problem cannot be fixed using the advice from that question?